# Lua value not changing?

Tags: lua

I use very simple Lua scripting in an online game called ROBLOX. My problem is that values in my scripts aren't changing! Example:

```
num = 0
while true do
    num = num + 1
    print(num)
    wait(1)
end
```

That should count up starting on 0, but the number won't change. Could this be from the ROBLOX website? I can't figure out what else it might be.

Comment: @Tim, I ran your code without the wait() part and it seems to be counting up normally..

Answer (score 6):

What happens with

```
local num = 0 
while true do 
    num = num + 1 
    print(num) 
    wait(1) 
end
```

?

Maybe some other part of the system is changing the global `num`.

Answer (score 0):

I just put your code in [the Lua demo](http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo) and it works fine if you remove the wait() function call.  I'm assuming you defined this function somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code.  You must be running it wrong.  Also, wait is a function defined in the Roblox API.  It is legit.

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in your code. If you are using ROBLOX, then I'm not sure how you're running it wrong as it is a fairly simple interface. I'll try it in ROBLOX and see if it errors for me.

To the people who were wondering about wait(): it's a ROBLOX-specific global function, that pauses the current task the amount of seconds in the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
local num = 0
while true do
    num = num + 1
    print(num)
    print(type(num))
    wait(1)
end
```

Comment: Note; type(num) is for debugging.